# mapping many journeys along a road network QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 500 x y journey origin co-ordinates for travel to one destination (ie it's journeys to a work base). I want to map the shortest route for all along the road network on one map (I have OSGB Meridian network) and show categorised volumes.

I've had a look at Road Graph but as far as I can tell that is for one journey origin only. MMGIS and Flowmapper are good for multiple journey origins but as far as I can tell only straight-line mapping is possible.

Is there a way of doing this please?

Comment: As far as I am concerned there is not traffic assignment add-on for QGIS right now.  There will be one in about a month, if you can wait :-).  In the meantime, have you considered doing it outside QGIS?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, it's great to learn that a traffic assignment add-on is in the pipeline - look forward to it.